# Where do I configure permissions on /var/log/audit?

Tags: 18.04, log

Issue I'm facing is that I am trying to set permissions on /var/log/audit.

If I issue `chmod -R g-wx,o-rwx /var/log/*` and then restart the service, the permissions are reset to: `drwxr-x---`

Where can I control this behavior?  I've checked

- /etc/logrotate.conf
- /etc/logrotate.d/*
- /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/*

Can't seem to find the ticket.

Appreciate your experience! Thank you.

Comment: Please don't mess with permissions on system files. If the group of the file is root or adm you have no reason to -ever- write to it yourself. **Please explain what you want to accomplish**, not what is not working for you. Setting permissions is not the correct method.

Comment: It's a component of the CIS Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS Benchmark, we need to harden instances per CIS.  The test that governs permissions on items in /var/logs is failing because of /var/log/audit

Answer (score 0):

The only control available for permissions on auditd logs is the `log_group` setting in the `auditd.conf` file. When this setting is present, all logging output will be group readable (mask `0750`); when the setting is not present, it will be readable only by root (mask `0700`). As you have noticed, this mode is also applied to the `/var/log/audit` directory itself when auditd is started.

In addition, log files will always have the write bit removed after they are rotated and will not be written further. These behaviors are all hard-coded in the auditd program.

Based on the `chmod` command in your question, I think you should be able to get the result you want by commenting out the `log_group` line in `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` and restarting auditd:

```
# systemctl restart auditd
# grep log_group /etc/audit/auditd.conf
#log_group = adm
# ls -ld /var/log/audit
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Jan 31 19:52 /var/log/audit
# ls -l /var/log/audit
total 26280
-rw------- 1 root root 1674289 Jan 31 21:22 audit.log
-r-------- 1 root root 8388712 Jan 31 19:52 audit.log.1
-r-------- 1 root root 8388786 Jan 31 18:55 audit.log.2
-r-------- 1 root root 8388631 Jan 31 18:08 audit.log.3
drwx------ 2 root root   16384 Jan 26 11:27 lost+found
```

Some systems may require a reboot for this configuration change to take effect.